# NotifyIcon not firing double-click event

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, notifyicon

I have a double click event for a notify icon that will bring up my main form. The double click event isnt firing. Even if I put a breakpoint in the code it never gets executed. Here is what I have so far:

```
 Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.Visible = False
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    e.Cancel = True

End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick

    Me.Visible = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.Activate()
    Me.BringToFront()
    Me.Focus()
    Me.Show()


End Sub
```

The excessive stuff is my way of trying eveything I can think of to get the form to show.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you subscribe properly to DoubleClick event?
Does program enter the DoubleClick handler if NotifyIcon1 is always visible?

Comment: I did double check that it was subscribed properly and it is. I went to the events, double clicked the double-click  option and it brought me to that sub. When I put a breakpoint inside the sub it never gets triggered.

Comment: I created a new program and just made a notify icon and used the code above and it works...so what am I missing or doing in my project that would kill this?

Comment: Create NotifyICon object in App.xaml.cs so it i will handle click or doubleClick for entire app.

Answer (score 0):

This is working when I just have a notifyicon in an app all by its self.  So what I do with the notifyicon works. What else could be wrong??